# Can I use 'more younger' in some cases?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage

Let's assume a woman is 50 and looking for a younger guys above 30 and I am 20. Would this be a right sentence?

> I see you are looking for a younger man, but why not even more younger?

Comment: Just omit the 'more' and have it as "...why not even younger?"

Comment: It would be grammatically incorrect, but the scenario you describe is informal enough that you could get away with it.

Comment: If you want to impress her with your youthfulness, using broken English doesn't quite get you there. :)